# Git: How to download latest version of repository files without downloading the whole repository?

Tags: git, github, repository

I would like to download PHPMailer from GitHub. The URL is the following:

https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

I am on a Linux box with `git` installed. I want to download the latest version of `PHPMailer` without downloading the whole repository.

Is this possible? What `git` command do I issue to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git clone with --single-branch will get only the branch desired.
Git clone with --depth=N will get only the N most recent commits (--depth=1 will clone only repo HEAD).

Ofc, you can combine them. But with --depth=N you will be able to see only the most recent history (of last N commits).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve what I wanted with the following Linux command:

```
 wget https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/archive/master.zip
```